# How to retrieve yelp category_filter with PHP? A JSON object inside a JSON object

Tags: php, json, multidimensional-array, yelp

I am working with the Yelp API v1 and i'm trying to get the category_filter which is stored in  category object.A small part of my JSON looks like this:

```
"businesses": [
{
 "address1": "800 N Point St",
 "phone": "4157492060",
 "categories": [{
"category_filter": "newamerican",
"search_url": "http://www.yelp.com/search?cflt=newamerican\u0026find_desc=\u0026find_loc=800+N+Point+St%2C+San+Francisco+94109",
"name": "American (New)"
}],
 "name": "Gary Danko",
 }]
```

My php script looks like this:

```
<?php
$yelpstring = file_get_contents("PATH TO JSON", true); 

$obj = json_decode($yelpstring, true);
foreach($obj['businesses'] as $business){
echo "Restaurant name: " . $business['name']."<br/>";
echo "Restaurant Type: " . $business['categories']['category_filter']."<br/>";
echo "Address 1: " . $business['address1']."<br/>";
echo "Phone: " . $business['phone'] ."<br/>";
echo "<hr>";
}
?>
```

I'm getting the name,address1 and phone,but not the category_filter i get a php error that says:

"Notice: Undefined index: category_filter in file.php on line 12"

I don't understand what i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

`$business['categories']['category_filter']`

is wrong

You have to use: `$business['categories'][0]['category_filter']`

In your json is "[{" which means that there is an array (/object, decoded as assoc-array) in another array.